# What is the origin of the HTML tag name: "<TD>"

Tags: html, html-table

I know it's a little off-topic, but what is the origin of the tag name "TD" used in HTML table markup?

"TH" seems like it should stand for "Table Header" and "TR" for "Table Row", but what about "TD"?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Looking at the [HTML spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/tabular-data.html#the-td-element), it seems that it's an abbreviation for "table data cell", whereas `th` is an abbreviation of "table header cell".

Answer (score 12):

The meaning of `<td>` is "table data"

Answer (score 7):

TD = Table Data ... Intuitive, no?

Comment: No, i know only rows and columns.

Answer (score 7):

I always assumed it stood for "Table Data"